# Krusader automatically opens newly created text files

Tags: gedit, krusader

I want to disable the auto open newly created text files with the internal editor in Krusader. Always when I make a new text file in Krusader with right-click + Create new + Text file, Krusader opens it with its internal editor. I like to use gedit for my text/code files. So I always have to first close the Krusader internal editor and then double-click the file to open it again with gedit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Krusader settings**

Krusader > Settings > Configure Krusader > General -> Viewer/Editor tab and add your favorite.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. I just had to type gedit in that field and any new text file created is opened with gedit. Krusader still opens it automatically at the file creation time.

Comment: Don't know why, but if I put `code` here to run VS Code, it does not launch. While it works from the terminal :(